# Почему я не могу считать данные с .env в ReactJS? Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: reactjs, .env

[image: На таком уровне находится мой файл .env]

В моем обычном js файле я пытаюсь найти переменную в файле `process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY`, но находит только `undefined`.

Comment: + переменная создана в этом файле(

Comment: Пишите в обычном файле, а в тегах reactjs? Так он не обычный получается?

Comment: да, получаеться. Ну пишу экшн для диспатча. А экшену нужна вот эта переменная. Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [документации](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) есть информация на эту тему, и там говорится, что переменные должны начинаться с `REACT_APP_`, что у вас не сделано.

И так же стоит обратить внимание на строку:

```
The environment variables are embedded during the build time.
```

Что значит, что нужно перезапускать билд после каждого изменения `.env` файла.

Comment: Спасибо). Очень помогло. То что надо)